# c++ super class define static member variable for subclass

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

Not sure whether this is the right way to describe it, but I want to define a super (abstract) class and several classes will inherit from that. The question is I want super class to define set of static member variables for subclasses. But they are not *static* to the super class.
Example,

```
class abstractExchangeClient{
// Define something here
}
class aExchangeClient: public abstractExchangeClient{
}
class bExchangeClient: public abstractExchangeClient{
}
```

If I do it this way:

```
class abstractExchangeClient{
    static double fee;
}
```

Then the 'fee' is static to abstractExchangeClient (please correct me if wrong).So is there any feature in c++11 (or whatever) to achieve this?

@IgorTandetnik In case that there are more than one name-shared static members, and some of them should be initialized to zero and some of them other values. It will be ideal if i can have a place to declare those static members for subclasses, and initialize them ( to zero or other values accordingly) and probably also log out some messages for these initialization steps. Without such a mechanism, I have to define those name-shared static variables in every subclasses and do the same initialization from time to time.

Comment: That is not possible but it would be nice if you were to explain why you think you need something like this.

Comment: Why can't each derived class define its own member, if it needs one? How do you plan to use all those "half-static" members? Imagine that you somehow managed to achieve what you want - show the code that would make use of it.

Comment: Would it be better to say that you want to require all of your subclasses to have this static attribute, but have that attribute be different for each class instead of shared across all?

Comment: I guess a functionally-close-enough equivalent is to make a template parameter. But that won't allow the member to be `float`.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck like the example above, I want each concrete has a static 'fee', but they have different value.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik because they have something common, for example, same name. or I can initialize them to zero together

Comment: `because they have something common, for example, same name` Why is this significant? Is there some code that relies on this fact? Then show that code. `or I can initialize them to zero together` Then show how you plan to do that. You see, you seem to expect to be able to somehow manipulate these data members generically. I'm not sure you've thought that part through, in which case this is an instance of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). So, take a step back and explain what problem you are *really* trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare static data for each subclass in your super class. You can achieve something similar by defining the structure of your static data in your super class then declaring the static data in each subclass:

```
class abstractExchangeClient{
    struct SData {
        // define your common static data here
    };
};

class aExchangeClient: public abstractExchangeClient{
    static SData s_data;
};

class bExchangeClient: public abstractExchangeClient{
    static SData s_data;
};
```

Comment: That's won't compile.

Comment: Well, try to compile it, and the compiler will tell you what's wrong with it, with specificity. But if you need a hint: what's the name of the static data member you've supposedly declared?

Answer (score 2):

So you want each of your derived classes to have a static data member? I think this is a good place to apply the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template<typename T>
struct FeeOf {
  static double fee = 0.0;
};
struct Derived : public SomeBase, public FeeOf<Derived> {
  // not necessary, the name of the static data member
  // is already in scope.
  using FeeOf<Derived>::fee;
};
```

I don't think there's a reasonable way to implement this solely in that base class.

Comment: `using` directive is not necessary (unless the derived class wants to also declare some other member named `fee`).

Comment: Oops, indeed. I'll add a note.

Comment: So basically you have a templated wrapper for a static member, and inherits that base-wrapper just like the subclass owns a static member, right? @DanielJour

Comment: Yes, for code using the derived class it's like that class had the static member.

Comment: @MattSun If you want to initialize those statics to different values (as you noted in comment), this is not a solution - you would still need an explicit specialization, which could result in even larger code than manual defining each static for child types.

Comment: This seems the best detour option for now.